# Jupyter kernel fail connecting to virtualenv

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have installed the virualenv in cmd with the steps following:

1.)python -m venv tfod

2.).\tfod\Scripts\activate

3.)pip install ipykernel

4.)python -m ipykernel install --user --name=tfod

All works fine until this steps. It showed up this line -> 'Installed kernelspec tfod in C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\tfod

**It successfully added in jupyter, and I able to see it in notebook**

However when I click the "abc" environment it cannot connect to the venv as picture shown belowed
[image: Example]

**And this below is the error shown in jupyter terminal**

[image]

**And below is the library inside my virtualenv**

[image]

Method tried, but didn't work:
i) Upgrade ipython
ii) Downgrade tornado to 5.1.1
iii) Reinstall anaconda

I don't what is going wrong. Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: Is it the same if you try it with an empty environment with only jupyter and ipykernel installed? Does it work outside this environment (and in other environments)?

Comment: @nocibambi  Yeah it is still the same. It only works with a base environment which is python 3. New created environment is unable to connect jupyter kernel.